# R cannot be resolved to a variable - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am learning Android development and I am using the book Professional Android 4 Application Development written by Reto Meier. I am using Eclipse with the ADT plugin to follow the examples in the book. I have already read several existing posts about this issue and have tried several methods to fix it. My code is exactly as the code is in the book. Please help me, I'm anxious to move on in the book but I don't want to skip past things but I've at this stupid bug for over three hours. It's a simple To-Do List app. Here's my main Activity class.

```
package com.example.todoolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ToDoListActivity extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate your View
```

**LINE 19**  setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

```
    // Get references to UI widgets
```

**LINE 22**  ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);

**LINE 23**  final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

```
    // Create the Array List of to do items
    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Create the Array Adapter to bind the array to the List View
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                  todoItems);

    // Bind the Array Adapter to the List View
    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
          if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
              (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myEditText.setText("");
            return true;
          }
        return false;
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Here's my XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
    android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
  />
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my strings.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">ToDoList</string>
  <string name="addItemHint">New To Do Item</string>
  <string name="addItemContentDescription">New To Do Item</string>
</resources>
```

I went to my Android SDK Manager already and installed all the build tools that were not installed and then restarted the SDK Manager and cleaned my project several times and rebooted Eclipse and even rebooted my computer. Please help, at this point, I just want to move on and get this stupid error fixed. I've also added import statements and removed import statements as suggested by people on other posts. It did not fix the issue. Eclipse is giving the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error three times in my Activity class (lines 19, 22, and 23).

Comment: Does Eclipse show any errors in any of your XML resource files? That's a common cause of ADT not generating `R` and causing this error. If your resources are fine, I would try a clean and rebuild.

Comment: try to clean your project or refresh it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: Once delete R file. Then clean and rebuild your project from eclipse menu.

Comment: Try Ctrl + Shift + O. Its alphabet "O" and not zero.

Comment: And your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable time and energy. I have solved this problem by just importing the project into eclipse rather than hand-coding the projects myself, although I like hand-coding it because I learn more and get better practice that way.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happen to me , and i passed a day to fix this. really this is a stupid error. i am just shearing my experience, may be it would helpful to you . First look carefully when you type this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);` hear your starting point `R.l` then eclipse should open a suggestion for you look like this[image: auto suggestion by eclipse]

you import the second one not `layout-android.R` . the second one is created in your project hear `com.example.gridtest` is the project package name . then focus your imported section in your code 
[image: import your R.java]

ok look this `import com.example.gridtest.R;` its **important** . If you already import this `android.R` then remove it. Thank you hope it works . ( you don't need to do this always but if you face this kinda problem then do this )